# Can I create a new column that gets its values by averaging values based on specified criteria in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, powerquery, data-transform

I am trying to create a new column in my data set that is currently in Azure that gets its values from averaging all rows in a specified column if values in that row meet certain conditions, conditions that change based on which column the calculated value is going into.  I was able to do this in googlesheets however I cant seem to find a way to accomplish this in Azure Data Factory.

This is a simple example of what my google sheets equation did if that equation was in cell E2.

=averageifs(D:D,C:C,C2,A:A,A2,B:B,"<"&B2)

Essentially what my data is, is game statistics from all NFL Games in the past 10 years with each row being a specific game, and I am trying to create a calculated row that gives (in this case) the average number of points a team is scoring per game going into that game. So obviously the season needs to match the season of the current row, the week needs to be less than the current rows week, and the team name needs to match the current rows team name.

I have tried using Power Query however I am not super knowledgeable in the Power Query M Language and I couldnt find any great resources online for an AverageIf statement of this nature.

I have also tried using Azure Data Flows with a window transformation and utilizing the AvgIF() function however Im not sure how to reference other values in the current row. For example, I can hard code AvgIF(AND(season == 2022, week <= 7, team_name == "Broncos"), points) however I dont know how to make the "2022","7", and "Broncos" so they change depending on what values are in the current row.

Im more than willing to test out other cloud platforms or services if they are cheap and beginner-ish friendly, I just want to automate a data pipeline for running these transformations then inserting the data in an ML logistic regression model.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the running average points of each team, you can use the **windows transformation** in dataflow. Below is the approach.

- Sample data is taken in source transformation.

| Season | week | team | point |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | RCB | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | RR | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | MI | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | RCB | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | RR | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | MI | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | RCB | 3 |
| 1 | 3 | RR | 3 |
| 1 | 3 | MI | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | RCB | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | RR | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | MI | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | RCB | 4 |
| 2 | 2 | RR | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | MI | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | RCB | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | RR | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | MI | 1 |

Table:1 Sample input data

- Then **Windows transformation** is taken and Windows settings are given as,

```
1. over: season.team
2. sort: team ascending
3. range by: range: unbounded to current row
4. windows column: point_avg=avg(point)
```

[image: gif1]

**Output:**

| Season | week | team | point | point_avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | MI | 3 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | MI | 2 | 2.5 |
| 1 | 3 | MI | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | RCB | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | RCB | 4 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 | RCB | 3 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | RR | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | RR | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | RR | 3 | 2.333333333 |
| 2 | 1 | MI | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | MI | 2 | 2.5 |
| 2 | 3 | MI | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | RCB | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | RCB | 4 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | RCB | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | RR | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | RR | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | RR | 3 | 2.333333333 |

table:2 window transformation result.